# How do i save pic to the same png rather than creating a new png each time a pic is taken

Tags: raspbian, camera, image

i have a question, How do i save pic to the same png rather than creating a new png each time a pic is taken

this is the command that execute the pic:

```
*cd ~
mkdir picture
cd picture
screen
raspistill -o a%04d.jpg -t 21600000 -tl 30000*
```

taken from this website: 
http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-time-lapse-photography-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20794

Answer (score 1):

The command you want to change is `raspistill -o a%04d.jpg -t 21600000 -tl 30000*`

The filename portion of that follows the -o switch: `a%04d.jpg` I'm not sure whats being replaced without further study but the % is allowing the expanded file name to change with each run.

Change that to a plain file name such as `photo.jpg`.

Resulting in `raspistill -o photo.jpg -t 21600000 -tl 30000*`

Now each new photo will replace the last.

Note: your title reflects .png the command however clearly has .jpg for file type.